# PWA. Local development with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, connection, progressive-web-apps, webpack-dev-server

I'm working with the React Create App and implementing PWA features. I configured PWA manifest successfully, the app can be installed. Now I'm working on Offline mode and here is a problem.
For local development, CRA uses webpack dev server. The app runs on http://localhost:3000

When I add the app to my Desktop and turn off the internet and the webpack dev server I'm facing the error: **The webpage at http://localhost:3000/index.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.**

It looks like it doesn't work without the working server, eg. a connection. 
So I can't test the PWA features because it just doesn't work in a Standalone Mode without any connection (internet & webpack dev server) but I have to.

Is it possible to handle it somehow? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Basically my question is: How to the PWA Offline mode locally in a Standalone mode when PWA installed on Homescreen and the Internet and Dev server are turned off.

Thanks for any help!
Kind Regards.